# Cannot use process substitution in bash

Tags: bash, shell, tee, process-substitution

I have a bash script ([source](https://github.com/horazont/xmpp-echo-bot)) which must redirect openssl output to another bash script:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 \
  openssl s_client \
    -starttls xmpp \
    -xmpphost "$domain" \
    -connect "$host:$port" \
    -quiet \
    < "$pipename" \
  | (printf '%s %s\n' "$jid" "$authstr"; \
     stdbuf -o0 tr '>\n' '\n\001') \
  | stdbuf -o0 tee "$debug_recv" \
  | stdbuf -o0 "$thisdir/echoz.sed" \
  | stdbuf -o0 tee "$debug_sent" \
  | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n' \
  | stdbuf -o0 tr '\001' '\n' \
  | tee >( bash commandparser.sh >> /dev/pts/0 ) \
  > "$pipename"
```

But it gives an error:
`./echoz.sh: 38: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

If i do just the same in command line it works fine:

```
$ echo "[DATA]" | tee >( bash commandparser.sh >> /dev/pts/0 )
------------------NEW MESSAGE-----------------
From: 
To: 
Type: 
Text: 
------------------NEW MESSAGE-----------------\n\n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your script](https://github.com/horazont/xmpp-echo-bot/blob/master/echoz.sh) starts with `#!/bin/sh` and `sh` is not necessarily `bash`. If you want your script to run with `bash` then use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Run it through ShellCheck.net.

```
Line 30:
    < "$pipename" \
      ^-- SC2094 (info): Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.
 
Line 38:
    > "$pipename"
      ^-- SC2094 (info): Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.
```

Your problem might be just as Ed said though - `sh` *might* be `bash` under the hood - my Git Bash emulation's `sh` allows `>(...)` constructs, but other versions may not, so I'd use explicitly use `bash`, or check to confirm your target system's `sh` can handle all those features.

I'd also try very hard to reduce the *noise* of that script...

Comment: As i mentioned higher `#!/usr/bin/env bash` helped to stop error to appear. But i have no output from `commandparser.sh` execution now.

Comment: We don't have a copy of that code. Try simplifying your structure for testing. Some *one* problem at a time, and build up the solution minimally until it works.